# Different results with ON/OFF modes of strict compliance with ANSI C

Tags: c, gcc, ansi-c, trigraphs

Why when the `ON` or `OFF` mode of strict compliance with `ANSI C` program produces different results? Compliance with strict about writing of the reasons that most modern industrial compilers default to some expansion of its own language, and some by default is *C99*, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
int main (void)
{
  int len; 
  len = strlen ("??=");
  printf ("len=%d\n", len); 
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the result. In both cases submitted compiler option `-w` to suppress warnings:

```
$ gcc t.c -w
$ ./a.out
len=3

$ gcc t.c -ansi -w
$ ./a.out
len=1
```

Comment: suppressing warnings is never a good idea :) there is no smoke without fire. (still +1 for `int main (void)`)

Comment: I'm curious - did you just happen by chance to use `"??="` as a test string, were you running into weirdness in a larger program and narrowed it down to this, or did you already know that `"??="` was a trigraph but still weren't sure about the different results?

Comment: @Michael Burr I deliberately used the trigraph. But I met them recently, so have not yet figured out the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it is not in ansi mode `gcc` is not converting the trigrpah `??=`(*length 3*) to `#`(*length 1*) which explains the length difference.

If you had not suppressed warnings `gcc` would warn that it is ignoring the [trigraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) in the non ansi mode(*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ba809bead78a150)*):

> warning: trigraph ??= ignored, use -trigraphs to enable [-Wtrigraphs]

You can read more about dialect options in the [Options Controlling C Dialect](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) section of the `gcc` docs. It says the following for `-ansi`:

> [...] It also enables the undesirable and rarely used ISO trigraph feature. [...]

Trigraphs are covered in the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `5.2.1.1` *Trigraph sequences* which says:

> Before any other processing takes place, each occurrence of one of the following
>   sequences of three characters (called trigraph sequences<sup>12)</sup>) is replaced with the corresponding single character.

and the following sequences include:

```
??=   #
```

Comment: @downvoter care to explain why you downvoted the question and my answer but seem to feel the other answer was worth upvoting?

Answer (score 2):

`"??="` is a trigraph. That's a very ancient idea to escape source code, if you can't enter in your terminal, what you want to enter.

`"??="` is actual `"#"`